# Adding multiple times integer to the middle of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add `c` times `b` integer to middle of the list.
Here my code:

```
listA.insert(int(len(listA)/2),b*c)
print("Your New List: ", listA)
```

When I change `(b*c)` to `([b]*c)` it works but I will convert it integer later. Therefore, it must be formal form like `[1,2,3,4,5]` not `[1,2,[3],4,5]`. If we say `listA = [1,2,3,4,5]` and let's suppose `b = 2` and `c = 3` I need to have `[1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5]`. Also, I don't have permission to use loop.

Comment: If you read the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), you would see that it says the `insert` function "Insert an item at a given position". So it can only put a single element there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list slicing:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
middle = len(lst) // 2
lst[middle:middle] = [2] * 10
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`b * c` will return an integer value. So that will not work.

You can use array slice and concat to do this.

```
listA = listA[0 : len(listA)//2] + [2] * 3 + listA[len(listA)//2 : len(listA)]
```

**Edit:**

As per the OPs comment, this array needs to be converted to a single integer. It can be done as follows:

```py
result = int("".join([str(number) for number in listA]))
```

If I put it all together

```py
listA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listA = listA[0 : len(listA)//2] + [2] * 3 + listA[len(listA)//2 : len(listA)]
print(listA)
result = int("".join([str(number) for number in listA]))
print(result)
```

Following is the output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
12222345
```

Comment: It works but after adding new elements, As I said I need to convert the list into integer. I mean if list [1,2,3,4], I will make it 1234. Therefore, your method cannot be converted in my code.

Comment: It does. You just have to do this: ```int("".join([str(number) for number in listA]))```